# How to explain leading gap when the constrain has a 0 setting

Tags: swift, xcode6, autolayout

I am new to Xcode 6 auto layout. In this screen shot I already set "Scroll View.Leading Equal SuperView Leading Margins" and constant 0. I expect the internal view appears with no leading gap.

However there is a leading gap in the storyboard.

1. how to explain this gap?
2. how should I correctly set constrains so that this gap will go away?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the constraint is set to "Superview.Leading **Margin**". Just deselect "Relative to margin" in the dropdown menu.